# How to measure pull force on a (kite) rope?

Tags: mobile-robot, sensors, raspberry-pi, uav

I'm building a kite flying robot, in which I've already got some sensors built in. I now also want to measure the pulling force on the rope which is attached to the kite. So I thought of attaching a hanging digital scale to the rope which can then measure the pulling force in kilograms. I of course need to read out the data from the scale using GPIO pins or USB.

Furthermore, I also have a raspberry pi installed within the kite and I want to measure some pull on ropes in the air. So if possible, I also need very small/light scales from which I can read out the data. It would be great if the scales can measure up to about 50kg, but with some pulleys about 20kg would be fine as well.

Unfortunately I can't find any digital hanging scale with a possibility to read out the data and which is reasonably light. There are some simple USB powered hanging scales, but I think they just use USB for charging, not for reading out data. And I also found [this one](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Kingtype-electronics-digital-luggage-crane-scale_857579100.html?s=p), but that's a bit overkill (too heavy and too expensive).

**So question #1: Does anybody know where I can get a simple existing hanging scale from which I can read out data?**

If needed I can also build something, but I just wouldn't know where to start. I did find [this page](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/100kg-hanging-scale-with-rs232-or_60558881053.html?s=p) on Alibaba, where they show the contents of the scale they offer:

[image]

So as far as I understand I need the component which I highlighted. But I have no idea how that component is called (what do I search for?) and whether it is actually doable to read it out from a Raspberry Pi.

**Question #2: does anybody know what the highlighted component is called, where I could possibly get it and if I can read it out from a Raspberry Pi?**

In conclusion; can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The component you highlighted is called a [tensile load cell](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tensile%20load%20cell&tbm=isch). You could buy one from a supplier, but it probably would be cheaper to buy a cheap digital hanging scale and taking the sensor out of it - at least I couldn't find one less than $100, ten times the price of a 50kg digital hanging scale.

You will need to do some analog conversion and amplification of the signal and then convert to digital with an ADC; I haven't done so myself but [Sparkfun's load cell tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-load-cells) seems a good start.

The other means is to create your own scale, with a stiff spring and some sensor detecting its movement, such as a digital depth gauge - which costs $3 and has a serial output.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Using the magic word "load cell" I found quite a few affordable load cells (±€30) and through your link to Sparkfun I also found the OpenScale board, which apparently makes converting the raw signal to a usb port really easy: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/openscale-applications-and-hookup-guide
Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

That is a load cell, comprised of four strain gages in a Wheatstone bridge, probably mounted in sheer mode to cancel out bending forces.

Answer (score 0):

What about a flex sensor? [Here's one for less than $10 at Sparkfun.](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10264)

Wherever there is tension there must also be flexsion in a crossmember of the kite or in the membrane. A little bit of experimentation might get you the data you seek.